# Cancellation law for sum of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be independent random variables such that $X+Y$ and $X+Z$ have the same probability distribution function. One might think that this implies that $Y$ and $Z$ have the same probability distribution function, but this seems to be false. On the other hand, I can't find a counterexample, so here's my questions:

1) is this really false? Where's the counterexample?

2) this is true at least in some cases, so what wound be the weakest assumptions under which this holds? (Assuming it's false)

Comment: This is a question about a cancellation law for characteristic functions: does $\phi \phi_1=\phi \phi_2$ imply $\phi_1= \phi_2$? The answer is no and counterexample is available in Volume 2 of Feller's book. If $\phi (t) \neq 0$ for all $t$ then $Y$ and $Z$ have the same  distribution.

Comment: Well, I guess this is it. Thanks for the answer.